# React map function if else condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use the map function to add a condition to display the email link.

If item contains email, display it.

However, it still does not work as it should showing "no link", console logs showing correct. I will be grateful for any help.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import listIcon from '../img/list-icon.svg';

class FaqList extends Component {
  state = {
    items: [
      { id: 1, name: "Lorem.", answer: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.", email: "hello@email.com", expanded: false },
      { id: 2, name: "Lorem.", answer: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.", expanded: false }
    ]
  };

  render() {
    let link;

    const isEmail = this.state.items.map(item => {
      if (item.email) {
        console.log(item.email); // showing email
        link = 'show link';
      } else {
        link = 'no link';
      }
    });

    return this.state.items.map(el => (
      <div
        key={el.id}
        onClick={() => this.handleToggle(el.id)}
        className={el.expanded ? "faq__columns--item--active faq__columns--item" : "faq__columns--item"}
      >

        <div className="faq__content">
          <p className="mb-0">{el.answer}</p>

          {link} // Template here

        </div>
      </div>
    ));
  }

}

export default FaqList;
```

Comment: Can you share your output? or try creating a fiddle.

Comment: If your last item is false, all will return `no link`, if your last item is true, all items will return `show link`.. Not sure that's what your after.

Comment: Replace `{link} // Template here` with `{el.email ? <div>el.email</div> : null}`.

Comment: `const isEmail =` that's also going to not be very useful, it's just going to be an array of `undefined`.

Comment: @Keith, You are absolutely right, it won't work because the {link} will always have the last value. Thanks

Comment: @Ranjan Your way is much cleaner and works perfectly. There is also no need to create a new function. Perfect, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no need for isEmail, using jsx power you can control the email link visibility inside the map function in render like that:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.items.map(el => (
        <div
          key={el.id}
          onClick={() => this.handleToggle(el.id)}
          className={
            el.expanded
              ? 'faq__columns--item--active faq__columns--item'
              : 'faq__columns--item'
          }
        >
          <div className="faq__content">
            <p className="mb-0">{el.answer}</p>
            {el.email && <div>email: {el.email}</div>}
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Prefer using a ternary operator instead of `&&`, wasn't working for me in a `react-native` project.

Comment: i use it like that in react native too, maybe you have to update your react-native version!

Answer (score 0):

You are already mapping over `items` in your `render` method. You don't need to map over `items` again to render some UI based on the presence or absence of the `email` key, it can happen in your main `map`, like so (line 38) : https://codesandbox.io/s/great-tree-c12ks

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
 render() {
  return <>
   {this.state.items.map(el => (
      <div
        key={el.id}
        onClick={() => this.handleToggle(el.id)}
        className={el.expanded ? "faq__columns--item--active faq__columns--item" : "faq__columns--item"}
      >
        <div className="faq__content">
          <p className="mb-0">{el.answer}</p>
          {el.email ? <div>show link</div> : <div>no link</div>}
        </div>
      </div>
    ));}
   </>
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `link` variable needs to be an object i.e.:

```
{  
  1, 'show link',
  2, 'no link'},
  ...
}
```

... where 1, 2, 3... (the keys) are the id's of your items, so you could then add links in render like this: `{link[id]} // Template here`
In that case here's a quick fix:

```
  const link = {};

  const isEmail = this.state.items.map(item => {
    if (item.email) {
      console.log(item.email); // showing email
      link[id] = 'show link';
    } else {
      link[id] = 'no link';
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for ?

```
_render_email(obj){
obj.email && console.log(obj.email);
return (obj.email)? <div>obj.email</div> : null;
}

 render() {
    return this.state.items.map(el => (
      <div
        key={el.id}
        onClick={() => this.handleToggle(el.id)}
        className={el.expanded ? "faq__columns--item--active faq__columns--item" : "faq__columns--item"}
      >

        <div className="faq__content">
          <p className="mb-0">{el.answer}</p>

          {
               this._render_email(el)                   
          } // -> modified 

        </div>
      </div>
    ));
  }
```